# Test scope variables inside a non-scope method that is initiated inside if condition

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Code:

```
if($scope.someValue){
init();
}

var init = function(){
$scope.anotherVal = true;
}
```

Test case:------------------------

```
describe('test 1', function(){
it('spec 1', function(){

 //I could'nt figure out how to initiate the init() method in my test case?

 $scope.someValue = true;
 expect($scope.anotherVal).toEqual(true);
});
});
```

*//error: Expecting undefined to equal to true.*

Can anyone help me figure out how to initiate the init() method. Moving the if condition into another method is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code you are calling the function `init` before it was declared. Be aware that you are using function expression. Function expression is not hoisted means when you declared a function it was not move to the top of the scope.

> Hoisting is a JavaScript mechanism where variables and function
>   declarations are moved to the top of their scope before code
>   execution.

Example of Function Expression:

```
init(); // Output undefined

var init = function() {
  console.log('It is not hoisted!!!');
}
```

function declaration is only be hoisted means it doen't matter wheter you declared it before you are calling the function

Example of Function Declaration:

```
init(); // Output Hoisted...

function init() {
  console.log('Hoisted!!!')
}
```

**Update 1**:

If you are interested in this topic here's the link [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: The init() method works fine. My question was how can i initiate it in jasmine test case.